# Distribute a twitter4j app without leaking Consumer Key and Secret

Tags: java, jar, twitter4j

As we know that a java jar file can be easily reverse engineered to get the source code, how should I distribute my twitter app which has been made using twitter4j so that on decompiling the jar file, the user is not able to get the app key and secret?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a obfuscator program like one of the below suggestions:

http://proguard.sourceforge.net

http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.html

http://www.e-t.com/jshrink.html

http://home.comcast.net/~shvets/Programs/Tools/CafeBabe/

Comment: I think it is a common problem.Hence there must be a standard solution. I agree with the solutions you have provided.But I still want.....

Comment: Java is mainly designed for server-side programming. This is why you should use above programs for obfuscation. I've never heard of any standard solution so far.